# How do I create a proper test environment for "logon trigger"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a glitch in a company software that creates many connections for a specific software. After 3 connections, people cannot log anymore. If they do not close the whole software, they "stay connected" and sometimes the same user on the same computer is "logged 3 times" on the same software.

I tried creating a logon trigger to prevent that, but I had massive issues. I could not even log on the admin account anymore.(with a backup, we manage to fix the problem though) I am a bit concerned about trying this again without having a proper test environment for logon triggers.

I want to be able to delete trigger or disable them if they cause issues. I want to be able to allow only 1 connection at a time to this software and prevent users from connecting twice.

Comment: Sounds like it would be better to fix the software glitch than try something hokey on the database server.

Comment: This belong to a 3rd party company, so I have no idea how much I can modify the software based on legislation.

Comment: To answer your first question - you install a test instance and create/test your trigger in that instance as best you can. Then, and only then, should you attempt to try this in the (presumably) production instance. However, it sure seems to me like your path is likely to cause this software to no longer work correctly. The app has some bug - any connection it opens it most likely expects to open successfully. Forcing these "extra" attempts to fail is likely to cause problems the application cannot understand or handle.